Writing Spark Job processed data to Iceberg table in AWS Glue
I am building a simple flow, reading data from the database in AWS catalog, applying some processing using Spark and I need to write the output to an Iceberg table in my Datalake in S3.
I keep getting the error below:
Session failed to reach READY instead reaching terminal state FAILED.
Current session is in an unhealthy terminal state. If you wish to create a new session use %stop_session before executing any further statements.


However, earlier, I tried writing the output to simple Parquet in my S3 datalake and it got created successfully
Here is the current Glue Notebook cells I am using:
Then, I try to configure Iceberg using %%configure:

%%configure
{
  "conf": {
    "spark.sql.extensions": "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions",
    "spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog": "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog",
    "spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse": "s3://s3-bucket-fabric/",
    "spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl": "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog",
    "spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl": "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO"
  },
  "args": [
    "--datalake-format",
    "iceberg",
    "--enable-spark-glue-datasource",
    "true"
  ]
}



Finally, below is my Spark Job:

import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, to_timestamp, to_date, when

# Initialize GlueContext
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# Set Spark configurations for Iceberg
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse", "s3://s3-bucket-fabric/")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO")

# Load the data from the Glue Data Catalog (Lake Formation database and table)
datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="transactions-db", table_name="raw", transformation_ctx="datasource")

# Define a function to convert DynamicFrame to DataFrame
def dynamic_frame_to_df(dynamic_frame):
    return dynamic_frame.toDF()

# Convert to Spark DataFrame
df = dynamic_frame_to_df(datasource)

# Define a list of columns to clean
columns_to_clean = df.columns

# Example Cleaning and Formatting Transformations
df = df.withColumn("Amount", regexp_replace(col("Amount"), "[^0-9.]", "").cast("float"))
df = df.withColumn("Time", to_timestamp(col("Time"), "H:m"))
df = df.withColumn("Date", to_date(col("Year") + "-" + col("Month") + "-" + col("Day")))
df = df.withColumn("MerchantName", regexp_replace(col("Merchant Name"), "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", ""))
df = df.withColumn("TransactionType", when(col("Use Chip") == 'Swipe Transaction', 'Physical').otherwise('Online'))

# Remove extra quotation marks from the "errors?" column values
df = df.withColumn("errors?", regexp_replace(col("errors?"), '"', ''))

# Remove unnecessary special characters and fill empty rows with "N/A"
for column in columns_to_clean:
    df = df.withColumn(column, regexp_replace(col(column), '[?!"#$%&\'()*+,./:;<=>@\[\\]^_`{|}~]', ''))
    df = df.withColumn(column, when(col(column).isNull() | (col(column) == ''), 'N/A').otherwise(col(column)))

# Write the transformed data to the Iceberg table
df.write.format("iceberg").mode("overwrite").save("glue_catalog.transactions-db.transactions-iceberg")

# Commit the job
job.commit()



I tried to stop the session and everything but I keep getting the same issue / error of that the session cannot get into READY state.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@user31081998 do not commit the job. Notebook itself is already a job, so no new one is needed.
